# Typdefs and implicit cast

Tags: c++, typedef, implicit-conversion

Example:

```
int main() 
{
  typedef int Oranges;
  typedef int Apples;

 /* ... a lot of other code */

  Oranges not_apples = 10;
  Apples apples = not_apples; // ??? confusing
}
```

Question: Can we forbid implicit casting for variables which were declared via typedefs?

Comment: Use a class instead of a typedef?

Comment: That obvious in that simple example, but sometimes it is even more confusing.

Comment: If you check your compiler documentation, there might be a warning you can enable. But in general it's allowed because a typedef is just an alias for another type. If you want strong type checking use classes as suggested by James.

Comment: Warning would be enough, thanks, I'll search for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`typedef` actually only creates an alias to a base type, so both types you created are actually just aliases to `int`. What you're looking for is `boost::strong_typedef`.

Comment: +1. In other words, no "implicit casting" is going on: the left- and right-hand-sides both have *exactly* the same type.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to conceal you typedef'ed types inside of a structure (class). Anyway, nearly all abstract values need a more detailed represantion than a simple "int", sooner or later.